# Calculate curvature form

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature

Given a Riemannian metric $g$, we can always compute curvature of Levi-Civita connection with respect to $g$, that is
$$
R_{ijkl}=\frac12(\partial_i\partial_kg_{jl}+\partial_j\partial_lg_{ik}-\partial_{i}\partial_lg_{jk}-\partial_j\partial_kg_{il})+g_{rs}(\Gamma_{ik}^r\Gamma_{jl}^s-\Gamma_{jk}^r\Gamma_{il}^s)
$$

However, I find it's quite difficult to compute in fact, for example, on Poincar'e disk $\Bbb{B}^n=\{x\in\Bbb{R}^n\mid |x|<1\}$, there is a Riemannian metric
$$
g=\frac{4\delta_{ij}\mathrm{d}x^i\otimes\mathrm{d}x^j}{(1-|x|^2)^2}
$$

In this case I find it's very very very difficult to compute $R_{ijkl}$, is there any easy way to compute this? Thanks in advance for any help in advance.

Comment: In the book *Gravitation* by Misner, Thorne and Wheeler there is a nice pedagogical chapter about the curvature one form $\omega$. They develop this exactly because direct calculations of $R$ are notoriously cumbersome.

Comment: The first few times you do this are quite painful. Have you done any other examples? Another suggestion is to do the case $n=2$ first without using indices or summation notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition of curvature form we have $$ R_{ijkl}=
E_i(\Gamma_{jk}^m g_{ml} ) -E_j(\Gamma_{ik}^m g_{ml} )
-\Gamma_{jk}^m\Gamma_{il}^n g_{mn } + \Gamma_{ik}^m \Gamma_{jl}^n
g_{mn} $$

where $E_i$ is a coordinate field, which is a canonical basis on
$\mathbb{R}^n$.

Further by definition of $\Gamma_{ij}^k$ we have $$ \Gamma_{ij}^k =
\frac{1}{2}g^{ks} (E_ig_{js} +E_j g_{is} - E_s g_{ij} ) $$

Recall $g=fg_0$ where $f(x)= \frac{4}{(1-r^2)^2},\
r=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}$ and $g_0$ is Euclidean metric.

Hence $f_k = E_k(f)=\sqrt{f}^3 (2x_k) $ so that we have $$
\Gamma_{ij}^k = \sqrt{f} (x_i\delta_{jk} + x_j\delta_{ik}
-x_k\delta_{ij} ) $$

Note that $\sharp \{ i,j,k\}=3$ implies $\Gamma_{ij}^k=0$

For the calculation of $R_{1221}$ we have
\begin{align*}R_{1221}&=
E_1(\Gamma_{22}^1f)-  E_2( \Gamma_{12}^1 f)
-\Gamma_{22}^m\Gamma_{11}^m f +(
\Gamma_{12}^m)^2 f
\\&\\
E_1(\Gamma_{22}^1f)-  E_2( \Gamma_{12}^1 f)
&=-2\sqrt{f}^3-3f^2(x_1^2+x_2^2) \\
-\Gamma_{22}^m\Gamma_{11}^m f +( \Gamma_{12}^m)^2 f&= f^2\{
2x_1^2+2x_2^2-\sum_{i>2}x_i2 \} \end{align*}

Hence $R_{1221}=-f^2$. Here $\{e_i=\frac{1}{\sqrt{f}} E_i\}$ is
orthonormal wrt a metric $g$ so that the sectional curvature for
$e_1,\ e_2$ is $-1$. Hence the metric $g$ has a const sectional
curvature.